# How to use a embedded font in Qt Style Sheet?

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I added a font name ":font/Oswald-Regular.ttf" in my .qrc resource file. I would like to use it in my Qt Style Sheet for all QLabels.

This is the code for Arial :

```
QLabel
{
color: white;
font: 10pt "Arial";
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the font to the font database in your `main`:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/Oswald-Regular.ttf");
```

You may want to check the function return value (0 indicates success) and/or the fonts available in the database:

```
  QFontDatabase db;
  for(int i=0; i<db.families().size(); i++)
  {
    qDebug() << db.families().at(i);
  }
```

and see if "Oswald" appears in the list.

Set the stylesheet to the label parent widget, from editor change stylesheet dialog:

```
QLabel { color: black; font: 24pt  'Oswald'; }
```

or programmatically in the widget constructor:

```
setStyleSheet("QLabel { color: black; font: 24pt  'Oswald'; }");
```

If  on Unix/X11 platforms, be sure `fontconfig` is installed.